# Assigning an integer to a char

Tags: java

I've been wondering about the reason why in Java we can assign an integer number directly to a char variable:

```
char a = 6;
```

but we can't assign an integer without a type cast

```
int bInt = 6;
char b = bInt; // error, cast first
```

I do understand that char is just 16-bit unsigned integer in the background, and that generally if we want to move a value from a wider range type to a lower range one, type cast needs to be explicit. But why is that not the case in the first example, what is the type of the `6` literal ?

Comment: `char a = 6;`: `6` is a compile-time constant. So the compiler knows for certain that it's within the char range.

Comment: Try assigning character like `70000` and you will see that compiler will complain. It doesn't for `6` because it *knows* it is within `char` range (16 bits) but it doesn't have that certainty for *every* value of `int` which could be stored in `bInt` variable.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that make sense.